# Plot a static and an animated line graph in same plot with plotly in R

Tags: r, plot, plotly, r-plotly, timeserieschart

My aim is to create 2 line graphs in the same plot area, however 1 should be static (always displayed), while the other animated (it will be displayed as soon as user clicks on the 'Play' button, as plotly provides). The concept is that we have a line graph with the actual values always displayed, and the animated one will be the fitted observations, showing how well they fit the actual line.

What I have achieved until now is to create both lines in an animated manner, however as mentioned before, I want the observations with `Type=="Actuals"` to be static, and the others (`Type=="Fitted"`) only animated . Please refer to my current script below.

Initial working data frame is `data2` which holds the actual and fitted values unified; with columns `RequCreatedFull-Date(as POSIXct), Requs_Qnt_pm(as num), Type(as Factor-indicates whether the record refers to 'actual' or 'fitted' observation), date(as num)` where
 `date=(year(RequCreatedFull_Date)+(month(RequCreatedFull_Date)-1)/12)`.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

#function definition for to be framed variable manipulation
accumulate_by <- function(dat, var) {
  var <- lazyeval::f_eval(var, dat)
  lvls <- plotly:::getLevels(var)
  dats <- lapply(seq_along(lvls), function(x) {
   cbind(dat[var %in% lvls[seq(1, x)], ], frame = lvls[[x]])
  })
  dplyr::bind_rows(dats)
}

#creation of to-be-used for framing variable
data2mod <- data2 %>%
  accumulate_by(~date)


#graph creation
my_graph<-data2mod %>%
             plot_ly(
               x = ~date, 
               y = ~Requs_Qnt_pm,
               split = ~Type,
               frame = ~frame,
               type = 'scatter',
               mode = 'lines', 
               line = list(simplyfy = F)
            ) %>% 
             layout(
                xaxis = list(
                  title = "x axis title",
                  zeroline = F
               ),
                yaxis = list(
                  title = "y axis title",
                  zeroline = F
               )
            ) %>% 
            animation_opts(
              frame = 100, 
              transition = 0, 
              redraw = FALSE
            ) %>%
            animation_slider(
              hide = T
            ) %>%
            animation_button(
               x = 1, xanchor = "right", y = 0, yanchor = "bottom"
            )
```

UPDATE:
`data2` table

```
#preparing 2 data tables for the plot (got to be merged with new Type var indicating actuals and fit observations)
agg_acts_rags_rf_ama2<-data.frame(agg_acts_rags_rf_ama, Type="Actuals", date=year(agg_acts_rags_rf_ama$RequCreatedFull_Date)+(month(agg_acts_rags_rf_ama$RequCreatedFull_Date)-1)/12)
agg_fits_rags_rf_ama2<-data.frame(agg_fits_rags_rf_ama, Type="Fitted", date=year(agg_fits_rags_rf_ama$RequCreatedFull_Date)+(month(agg_fits_rags_rf_ama$RequCreatedFull_Date)-1)/12)

names(agg_acts_rags_rf_ama2)[2]<-"Requs_Qnt_pm"
names(agg_fits_rags_rf_ama2)[2]<-"Requs_Qnt_pm"

#unifying the tables
data2<-rbind(agg_acts_rags_rf_ama2, agg_fits_rags_rf_ama2)
```

`agg_acts_rags_rf_ama` and `agg_fits_rags_rf_ama` hold only 2 columns, the `RequCreatedFull_Date` and a quantity column

Comment: Could you please provide the code for creating `data2`?

Comment: @Endre, updated my question with requested code, please check. Thank you.